# CSS spacing different between FF and Chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on this wordpress site: http://jillianssf.com/dev/

When I look at it in Chrome the words 'Welcome to Jillian's appears corrent... right up under the nav menu. The problem is when I look at it in Firefox it has a large space. This space was initially padding from the original theme's navigation.

I rearranged the navigation and then changed:

```
.site-main {
    padding-top: 78px;
}
```

to

```
.site-main {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Other CSS:

```
.nav-main {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
    height:0;   
}

.nav-main .container { 
    position: relative;
    bottom: -81px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    background: transparent url(http://jillianssf.com/dev/wp-content/themes/theflavour-child/imgs/nav-bg.png) repeat-x bottom left;
    height:81px;
}
```

I have searched using firebug and the standard FF inspector but can't find why this is still leaving such a large space.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? I'm using Firefox Developer 41.0a2 on Mac and it looks fine, the same as on chrome.

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The space is produced by the menu.

Comment: 2nd time in as many days i have seen this site with spacing issues. I gave up looking for the reason for the white space, there are many rules applied that should not be there to achieve what you want, but basically make the header element your parent div with position relative, put the image inside, let that size the header element and absolutely position the nav item. to the bottom of the header.

Comment: @david you are essentially correct. There are many rules added that are overwriting others. This is why I advise my clients to avoid wordpress templates at all cost.

Comment: @ray its not a wordpress problem just a author not thinking things ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Your were assigning `top` to a static element and it had an adverse affect on the document. Essentially, it was including the space from where the item was suppose to be.

Change `.nav-main` to an absolute element, and remove the `top` positioning.

**New**

```css
.nav-main {
    background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    transition: top 0.4s ease 0s;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**Old**

```
.nav-main {
    background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    top: -126px;
    transition: top 0.4s ease 0s;
}
```